# Format all numbers the same way in velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity

Is there a way to define a default format for all numbers in a velocity template.

I would like to avoid to use numberTool.format("myformat", $mynumber) for all number variables in my template.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that its not clear what "velocity template" is. But, there is a common way for number formating [java.text.NumberFormat](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); //or any other locale, e.g. = new Locale("en", "us");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
```

you can then set settings:

```
mf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

And then, when you otuput result:

```
nf.format(number);
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm really looking for an answer specific to velocity http://velocity.apache.org/

Comment: there is nothing that prevents you from putting the `NumberFormat` to you context and the call `$nf.format($number)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ReferenceInsertionEventHandler stuff.  Should let you create one to watch all reference events and format any that are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to format number in velocity template

```
NumberTool.format("#00,000.0", $mynumber)
```

format function mask the value of $mynumber with "#00,000.0".
Although it is the old thread but it may b useful for other people.